# Asymptotic behaviour of Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f,g$ be functions in $C_b\left(\left[\varepsilon,\frac{1}{2}\right]\right)$, $\forall \; \varepsilon > 0$, or equivalently $f,g \in C\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. 
We have $f(p) \overset{p \to 0}{\sim}g(p) $, meaning that $\limsup_{p \to 0}\left\lvert\frac{f(p)}{g(p)}\right\rvert < \infty$ and $\limsup_{p \to 0}\left\lvert\frac{g(p)}{f(p)}\right\rvert < \infty$.

My question is, if it holds that 
\begin{align*}
  \int_p^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx \overset{p \to 0}{\sim}\int_p^{\frac{1}{2}}g(x)dx \; \; \; ?
\end{align*}

I would be happy for any ideas.

Comment: What is $C_b?\,\,$

Comment: continuous, _bounded_ functions. the first line is as good as writing
$f,g \in C\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$.

Comment: A function in $C(0,1/2]$ need not be bounded.

Comment: We can assume $f,g$ are nonvanishing? (Else those divisions are not defined)

Answer (score 0):

The integrals are affected by the behavior of f, g everywhere and not just near zero,  so I'd say the answer is no.